# Is it possible to add multiple domain for wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress

I need to attach multiple domain names in my wordpress multisite.
   
Example: I have a main domain main.com and  I want to attach one.com & two.com to my main domain.
 I already know about 'subdomain.main.com' like network.
 Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a plugin available to do it in better way,

please check it here, it would help you : http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/